# Why I can't use "this" here? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create three input[type=range], but I just can't use onChange={this.handleChange}, there will be mistakes. If I change to {elem.handleChange}, there will be no mistake, but I still can't get the value.

```
var ColorBoard = React.createClass({
        getInitialState() {
            return {
                inputItems:[
                    {id:1, value:0},
                    {id:2, value:5},
                    {id:3, value:10}
                ]
            };
        },
        handleChange(event){
            console.log(event.target.value)
        },
        render() {
            var displayInput = this.state.inputItems.map(function(elem) {
                return <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id={elem.id} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
            });
            return (
                <div className="well clearfix">
                    {displayInput}
                    <span>{this.state.inputItems[0].value},{this.state.inputItems[1].value},{this.state.inputItems[2].value}</span>
                    <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Click</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: by mistake you mean exception or compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't specify the `this` pointer for `map`, so `this` will refer to the global scope.

Either:

1. Specify the `this` pointer: `displayInput = this.state.inputItems.map(fn, this);`
2. Use an arrow function
3. Capture `self` in the closure

Like so:

```
var self = this;
var displayInput = this.state.inputItems.map(function(elem) {
  return <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id={elem.id} onChange={self.handleChange} />;
});
```

Comment: Please mark such questions as duplicate instead of answering them, there are hundreds or questions related to binding on stackoverflow